# Javascript and php error

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, function

The url i am using is [this](http://abigtheme.esy.es/)

I have got a javascript(jquery) file called custom.js in which i am using:

```
(function ($) {
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.days').countdown({
            until: directorDate,
            layout: '{dn} {dl}',
            timezone: +7
        });
        $('#weather').openWeather({
            city: 'directorCity //The city is in a string.It used to be 'New York,US'
            placeTarget: '.weather-place',
            iconTarget: '.weather-icon',
            customIcons: 'dark/files/img/icons/weather/'
        });
        });
})(jQuery);
```

In my header i am using:

```
<script>var directorDate = new Date(<?php $date = get_option('director_date');?>
<?php if( $date) : ?>
<?php echo $date; ?>
<?php endif; ?>);
var directorCity = <?php $city = get_option('director_city');?>
<?php if( $city) : ?>
<?php echo $city; ?>
<?php endif; ?></script>
```

Basically what is happening is that the header gets the data from a file themeoptions.php (A form in the wordpress admin for a user to input data.I have not shown it because the structure of both director_city and director_date is the same there) and then custom.js gets the data from the header.

Now the countdown runs however the city is not displayed. Why is that so?

Comment: What's the format of the value returned by `director_date`, is it a String or an int, or what? If it's a String, you're not wrapping it in quotes.

Comment: Its a string wrapped it in codes but didn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try in your php replace this line:

```
var directorCity = <?php $city = get_option('director_city');?>
<?php if( $city) : ?>
<?php echo $city; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

with:

```
var directorCity = <?php $city = get_option('director_city');?>
<?php if( $city) : ?>
<?php echo "'".$city."';"; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Try and if it doesn´t work, send the result html from that php file.

Comment: Thank you so much.Let me check it out. And i'll give you the bounty

Comment: Did it worked? You needed the '' in the string for javascript to know it was a string.

Comment: Yes i got it but it worked locally. Now i'm testing it live.It would take a few minutes.

Comment: you could clean up that echo like this: <?php if($city){echo "'$city';";} ?>

Comment: Thank you @adearriba it worked.Here's your bounty.Wait i have to wait 23 hours more.Its the [SO] rule

Answer (score 0):

This line looks incorrect: `city: 'directorCity //The city is in a string.It used to be 'New York,US'`. It's reading all that line as a string (and probably throwing an error at at the N after the second single quote?).

It sounds like you're after the directory city name as held in `directoryCity`, so try changing that line to `city: directoryCity,`

If this doesn't work, can you check for errors in the javascript console and if any, post them?